# PHP Sort a multidimensional array by another array which contains the IDs

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

Hi, can anyone help me to sort a multidimensional array by another array?
**Array 1:**

```
Array(
    [0] => Array( 
        'id' => '58e9f01ff291c'
    ),
    [1] => Array( 
        'id' => '58e9f0590d6c0' 
    ),
    [2] => Array(
        'id' => '58ea5274219ac
    )
)
```

**Array 2:**

```
Array('58e9f0590d6c0', '58ea5274219ac', '58e9f01ff291c')
```

The second array contains the IDs of the first array and I would like to sort the first array by the IDs in the second array. How can I do this?
Best wishes and thanks for any help
Canned
**Update:**
I figured it out:

```
$return = array();
foreach($array2 as $sortId) {
    foreach ($array1 as $subKey => $subArray) {
        if ($subArray['id'] == $sortId) {
            $return[] = $array1[$subKey];
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried array_multisort? http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php

Comment: I know array_multisort but how can I combine it with Array 2? Best wishes, Canned

Comment: `$a = Array('58e9f0590d6c0', '58ea5274219ac', '58e9f01ff291c');
$a = array_map(function($i) { return array('id' => $i); }, $a);`